# Get selected elements in linked revit document using revit api

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am trying to get selection to work from a linked document without a result:

```
Document linkedDoc = testLinkedElement.GetLinkDocument();
UIDocument linkedUIDoc = new UIDocument(linkedDoc);
// Get the selection object from the UIDocument
Selection selection = linkedUIDoc.Selection;

// Get the selected elements
ICollection<ElementId> selectedElementIds = selection.GetElementIds();
```

I get an error when I try to instantiate the UIDocument from the linked document object
If I use the active UIDocument I have no access to the elements in the linked documents.

Any suggestions ?

I am trying to get selection to work from a linked document without a result
I am assuming that the selectedElementIds will be filled with selected elements

Comment: What i can guide you with is that you can't access the linked elements by creating a new UIDocument Instance through getting the liked document itself .
The selection must be initiated through the active UI document.

Comment: Please add how you are getting the `testLinkedElement` , because if it is the linked element , why are you trying to get it again?

Comment: and what do you want to do with the elements from the Linked Document ? , are you trying to modify them? , because that would fail as you should open a document even if in the background to make a modification in it.

Comment: Hi Mostafa, Thank you for your insight !. It is all about getting parameter information from selected elements from a linked mep file. I need to add this feature. I am not able till now to get the selection from  the active UI to get me the selected elements from the linked file.

Comment: I write you up an answer that may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample of Getting the element id from a linked element, you can try to modify this according to your needs and get the data you want from the Element.

```
public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
 {
     try
     {
         Reference selectedObj;
         UIDocument uidoc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument;
         Document doc = uidoc.Document;
         Selection sel = uidoc.Selection;
         selectedObj = sel.PickObject(ObjectType.LinkedElement, "Select Linked Element");
         RevitLinkInstance linkInstance = doc.GetElement(selectedObj) as RevitLinkInstance;
         Document linkedDoc = linkInstance.GetLinkDocument();
         ElementId xx = linkedDoc.GetElement(selectedObj.LinkedElementId).Id;
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
        return Result.Failed;
     }
     return Result.Succeeded;
 }
```